# How to Start a Service in a Specific Directory via Daemontools?

Tags: linux, centos, cd-command, exec, daemontools

I am using [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) to start my application.

In the run script, I have something like
exec taskset -c 2 [absolute path to my application]

But the problem is that one of the black box library my application expects it to run in a specific directory.

Now my question is how I can run my application in a specific directory without creating a subshell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply change the directory in the `run` script before you exec into the application. The current directory will be preserved across the `exec` call.

Something like the below in the `run` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/to/datadir
exec taskset -c 2 /path/to/bin/myapp
```

Comment: I swear it didn't work when I tried before posting.  Now it works!  Thanks!